# change language of html content using javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created some html pages with the content in english language. Now i need to change the language to Mandarin language(Singapore language) dynamically based on user selection without redirecting the pages.Please anyone help me to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you going to perform the translation and where will that data exist?  Are you going to deliver to the client both versions and dynamically show/hide content with JavaScript on the client?  Do you need the JavaScript to make an AJAX call to the server to get the translations and then dynamically replace the content on the client?  Or are you even hoping to have the JavaScript call some kind of translation service (Google Translate, perhaps?) to perform the translations directly and then replace the content on the client?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:
https://translate.google.com/manager/?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Check this out
[Language](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_global_lang.asp)

You can pass a variable as a attribute value, which will hold the language chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want that you have 2 choices :

*** Getting real content from Server** :
You cant do that on client side, you maybe have to have a web application fetching real content from DB as example and with AJAX everything will be awesome.

*** Getting translated content from Client Side** : 
You can do that using Google tools, and APIs , you can start from : http://translate.google.com/translate_tools
And do your customization.

I don't prefer using Google translation like that (add a drop down for translation) you can now why after you test that, its performance and view issues.

**Edit**: maybe this link help you too : http://labnol.blogspot.com/2005/11/add-language-translation-to-website.html